# Pushing message to multiple clients through SignalR

Tags: signalr

I am having a Chat app in which i have to push a message to all other users in that conversation, signalr works fine when i push message to all clients over 100 but when i loop over those 100 connections and send message individually then message receives slowly on client side and when I start to push messages faster then my server IIS worker goes to 100% CPU usage and message receiving on client end become more slower,

So help me finding the best way to send messages to specific user from signalr more than 100 users at same time

Comment: Attach a debugger to the process and find out what is going on (possibly an infinite loop?). SignalR should be able to easily handle more than a 1000 of connections.

Comment: Code executes smoothly but my iis keep pushing messages to clients slowly one by one with 100% cpu usage, by the way my server configuration is windows server 2012, 8gb ram, Xeon(R) 2.2 ghz, is it fine?

Comment: 100% cpu usage indicates that there is an infinite tight loop on one of the threads. Since your processor has more than one core it is still doing some processing (hence the responses are pushed to clients) but because the tight loop is stealing resources it happens much slower. IMHO solving the 100% cpu usage is the key here.

Comment: I find out that the issue is with the redis backplane, when i remove redis to be used as backplane it works fine, do you have any idea about it, i need to use redis because i have to use multiple machines

Comment: The Redis backplane has recently been migrated from BookSleeve to StackExchange.Redis but this has not shipped yet. Can you try a nightly build of SignalR 2.2.0 and the Redis backplane from https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetwebstacknightly and see if this helps? Alternatively you can wait for 2.2.0 - should not be long.

Comment: I Updated Signalr 2.1.2 and Signalr.Redis to current version and my redis server to 2.8 version and now this issue is resolved

Answer (score 4):

If it's a chat application, you may want to look into [groups in SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups). Simply create a new group for each "conversation" and join the users to the group.

From the documentation:

```
public class ContosoChatHub : Hub
{
    public Task JoinRoom(string roomName)
    {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
    }

    public Task LeaveRoom(string roomName)
    {
        return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
    }
}
```

Then you can simply message the group:

```
Clients.Group(groupName).addChatMessage(name, message);
```

Comment: In my case I generate individual message for all other user in that conversation depending on some requirements, and for that purpose i cannot push the same message to all users in that conversation, is there something else i can try?

Comment: And can you tell me is SignalR capable enough to send message individually to about 200 clients at a time? my server configuration is windows server 2012, 8gb ram, Xeon(R) 2.2 ghz
I am asking this because if some how i implement for the signalr group but in case when there would be 100 conversations having 2 to 3 users and all of them just push the message same time then it would behave in same way as it is now